# MySQL on duplicate key... get existing ID?

Tags: mysql, database, key

I'm using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to handle duplicate inserts on a table, in order that they are discarded.

In my case it's a simple table storing tags:

- `id` (int, PK, AI, unsigned, not null)
- `tag` (varchar 25, not null, unique)

This is working fine, but I need to retrieve the ID - either the insert ID, on successful insert, or the existing ID, if it's a duplicate.

I'm getting insert ID = `0` where `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` fires, which I guess is expected behaviour since no insert took place.

Is there anyway I can get the existing ID, or am I headed  to a separate read query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a third column `ModifiedDate` and use that:

```
insert into t(id, tag)
    select id, tag
    on duplicate key update ModifiedDate = now();
```

This will ensure that an update really occurs, and in turn, that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a value.

Comment: Be very careful with this approach; it can lead to very hard to trace and/or debug errors. It is possible that in very fast and repetitive actions, loops and so, the record could be updated more than once within the same second - that is, with the same datetime representation, thus effectively NOT updating the record although you are sure it is being done. I just this covered this in my code after hours of debugging. Maybe you could use an integer datatype and add one unit on each update, or add one second to the existing time value, and that.

Comment: @Pere . . . Interesting problem.  It would be solved with something like `on duplicate key update unneededcol = coalesce(unneededcol, 0) + 1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and @Utkanos: really the best way should be resorting to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`, as stated by the docs and several stackoverflow similar questions/answers. That causes the record to get updated even if there are no changes when an `UNIQUE` key already exists; you can test it by yourself.

Comment: @Pere +1 I tested and working as espected. With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`  working even if there are no changes